# Debugging help: web app is redirected to index (by possibly Owin) for first couple login attempts after an IIS Recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis, owin

So I am a little stuck. I have an MVC 5 application that uses Owin (did not use out of box implementation) for authentication.

The application runs fine except when I recycle the IIS7.5 app pool, then it starts to act up. When I recycle the pool (I wait about 2 minutes after) and attempt to log on, it will redirect me without error to the `index` page at least 2+ back-to-back times. Then eventually it will let me log in successfully. Please note that for the application under this app pool is using anonymous authentication.

Now I find this pretty odd, in all areas where this could error I have a try catch, and deal with it accordingly (none of these catches redirect to `index` without an error message). In addition, I implemented Elmah to see if any errors were slipping through, which none are.

There 2 reasons why this worries me:

1. Is it only happening after I recycle the app pool? I am not sure... Are users experiences this at random?
2. I have no idea what the source of this behavior is and am not sure how to debug it, are there any suggestions on how to do so?

My only guess is that there is something messed up with the cache or headers and a 401 is being returned thus causing owin to redirect using the `LoginPath`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/PunchAuthOp/Index")
        });
    }
}
```

Again, I am not sure why it would do that.

I looked at my HTTP traffic on HTTPFox and it looks like when this redirect occurs I am getting an `0 GET Aborted NS_BINDING_ABORTED` error. However upon comparing the successful query with the unsuccessful one I see no differences.

**I guess my question is, does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?**
Note: It does not happen when working through VS, it is only when deployed.